# No provider for ActivatedRoute - Angular 2 RC5

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

After upgrading to Angular 2 RC5 (from RC4) it seems I can no longer inject `ActivatedRoute` into my components.

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for ActivatedRoute!

Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { 
  ActivatedRoute
} from '@angular/router';

declare var module: {
  id: string;
};

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'mds-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
      'app.component.css'
  ],
  directives: []
})
export class AppComponent { 

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this._route.params.subscribe(params => console.log(_route));
  }
}
```

and here's my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

import { 
    routing, 
    appRoutingProviders 
} from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, CommonModule, RouterModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [ appRoutingProviders ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I checked the "Tour of Heroes" example and they do the exact same thing, there is no provider declaration for `ActivatedRoute` so what is going on here I wonder?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was browsing through Angular 2 issues on GitHub and found the solution to the above problem out of sheer luck (see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10714)).

I needed to add `routing` (see `import` above) to `imports` in `NgModule`, i.e.

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, CommonModule, RouterModule, routing ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [ appRoutingProviders ]
})
```

Seems Angular 2's error messages just got more confusing than they already have been.

I hope this answer is of some use to someone, I was about to pull my hair out already.

EDIT: By popular request, here's a snippet for the imported `routing` (off the top of my head, as I'm off work this week, let me know in the comments if there are any issues with it):

*app.routing.ts:*

```
export routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'sales', component: SalesComponent }
];

export routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

and in your `app.module.ts` you'd import this as follows:

```
import { routing } from 'app.routing'
```

Comment: what is the correct import for "routing"? i can't seem to find it

Comment: It's the exported `RouterModule`, you might as well write `imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]` where `routes` is `routes: Routes = [....]` from `app.routing.ts`.

Answer (score 31):

If you get this error in unit tests, you need to import RouterTestingModule

Comment: Was looking for this.

Comment: pls give complete info.

Answer (score 7):

I got this error during unit tests. Imported RouterTestingModule and used in my Testing module as below:

```
  beforeEach(
async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
      RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ path: 'orders/:id', component: OrdersComponent }])
    ],
    providers: []
  }).compileComponents();
})
```

);