# Downgraded Angular2 Component getting No provider for ActivatedRoute! error

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

Currently I have an Angular 2 component that is being downgraded as a directive and used in a bootstrapped hybrid Angular1/Angular2 application. I'm running into an issue when the component is loaded in the browser I get the following error:

> No provider for ActivatedRoute!

Note: the following, [No provider for ActivatedRoute - Angular 2 RC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942817/no-provider-for-activatedroute-angular-2-rc5) does not cover this use case.

This app still uses all the routing from the bootstrapped Angular 1 app and has been working just fine thus far; I haven't converted the routing to use the Angular 2 routing at this point. One of my requirements in the new component I built was to inspect query parameters. This could be done with the following code:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute)

route.queryParams.subscribe(
    data => this.Id = data['Id']);
```

The problem I *believe* is in the fact that the code above relies on the Angular2 router which as I mentioned is not yet being used in my hybrid bootstrapped application. So here is my question:

- Can I use the code I have above without using the Angular2 router and still inspect the query string parameters? The original Angular1 controller used `$routeParams` to get querystring information. This wasn't supported in my new Angular2 component. If the answer to the above is I can't use `ActivatedRoute` because I'm not using the Angular2 router, should I be trying to use this old method or use another; all I need to do is inspect route parameters in my component?

Comment: Add ActivatedRoute to providers of your NgModule or make sure RouterModule is added to imports

Comment: @BabarBilal - that doesn't work. I get the error, "Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRoute" According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509325/error-systemjs-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-activatedroute I need to have `imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ]` but again I don't have any Angular 2 routes defined as my post says. So this brings me back to my question - can I use `ActivatedRoute` without using Angular 2 routing?

Comment: No you cant because all routing providers came from RouterModule

Comment: If you are not using Angular 2 routing, are you using the AngularJS UI Router? Perhaps you are looking for [URL parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)?

Comment: @jim - no this application used `$routeProvider`